# асинхронная работа с геокодером

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть такой код (тайпскрипт)

```
map: any;
clusterer: any;
someArray:any; //содержит адреса, строки;

.....
function f() {
ymaps.ready().then(()=> {
  ymaps.geocode("Moscow").then((res:any)=>
  this.map = new ymaps.Map(..);
  this.clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer();
  someArray.forEach((address:any)=> {
    ymaps.geocode(address).then((gcrRes:any)=> {
      this.clusterer.add(new ymaps.Placemark('coords from address'...);
    }
 } //foreach closed
this.map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
...
```

и получается, что кластерер добавляется в карту до того как геокодер обработал адреса, и на карте ничего не выводится
Как в таком случае делать правильно?

Comment: Добрый день, не знаю тайпскрипт, но кажется должно сработать так: 


    .....
    function f() {
    ymaps.ready().then(()=> {
      ymaps.geocode("Moscow").then((res:any)=>
      this.map = new ymaps.Map(..);
      this.clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer(); 
    this.map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
      someArray.forEach((address:any)=> {
        ymaps.geocode(address).then((gcrRes:any)=> {
          this.clusterer.add(new ymaps.Placemark('coords from address'...);
        }
     } //foreach closed
    ...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить задачу, нужно использовать vow.Promise.all()

```
function f() {
ymaps.ready().then(()=> {

  ymaps.geocode("Moscow").then((res:any)=>

  let promises:any[] = []

  someArray.forEach((address:any)=> {
    promises.push(ymaps.geocode(address));
     }
 } //foreach closed
введите сюда код
  this.map = new ymaps.Map(..);
  this.clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer();
введите сюда код
Promise.all(promises).then(items=> {
items.forEach(item=> {
this.clusterer.add(new ymaps.Placemark('coords from item'...);
);
});

this.map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
...
```

Рабочий вариант находится на

```
https://codepen.io/iOgre/pen/yjbmMx/
```